# They give me this type error "sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found" for my codes

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import*
import string
import random

win = Tk()
win.geometry("500x400")
win.title("password generator")

def password_generator():
    character = list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "@#$&^!%")
    random.shuffle(character)
    
    password =[]
    password_length = 7
    
    for x in range(password_length):
        password.append(random.shuffle(character))
        
    random.shuffle(password)
    password= "".join(password)
    pass_word_l.configure(password)
    

u_name = Label(win, text="Usename:", font="arial,20").place(x=70, y=100)
pass_word = Label(win, text="Password:", font="arial,20").place(x=70, y=160)

u_name_e = Entry(win, width=30).place(x=170, y=100)
pass_word_l = Label(win, font=("arial", 13,"bold")).place(x=170, y=160)

G_pass = Button(win, text="Generate Password", width=20, borderwidth=5, command=password_generator).place(x=190,y=220 )

win.mainloop()
```

I tried creating a password generator but when i run the codes they gave me this type error: "sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found", and i can't identify my mistake

Comment: `password.append(random.shuffle(character))` random.shuffle does not return anything, so this always appends None.  Perhaps you meant `random.choice(character)`?

Comment: Thanks it worked, but i've got this attribute error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'configure'

Comment: That's because you're doing `pass_word_l = Label(win, font=("arial", 13,"bold")).place(x=170, y=160)`, and the place() function does not return anything.  You need to create the label as one step `pass_word_l = Label(win, font=("arial", 13,"bold"))` and then call place after `pass_word_l.place(x=170, y=160)`

Comment: please I've got an error again...................._tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-z^qLV4!"

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error. Because you left out keyword `text=from` configure in line 21. I including comment from @John Gordon.

```
from tkinter import*
import string
import random

win = Tk()
win.geometry("500x400")
win.title("password generator")

def password_generator():
    character = list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "@#$&^!%")
    random.shuffle(character)
    
    password =[]
    password_length = 7
    
    for x in range(password_length):
        password.append(random.choice(character))
        
    random.shuffle(password)
    password= "".join(password)
    pass_word_l.configure(text=password)
    

u_name = Label(win, text="Usename:", font="arial,20").place(x=70, y=100)
pass_word = Label(win, text="Password:", font="arial,20").place(x=70, y=160)

u_name_e = Entry(win, width=30).place(x=170, y=100)
pass_word_l = Label(win, font=("arial", 13,"bold"))
pass_word_l.place(x=170, y=160)

G_pass = Button(win, text="Generate Password", width=20, borderwidth=5, command=password_generator).place(x=190,y=220 )

win.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]